# Why does partitionIndex is not returned correctly the first time getPartitionIndex is called?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, quicksort

Following program sorts using first element of array as pivot but getParitionIndex doesn't work as expected. Specific question/observations given at end.

```js
var quickSort = function (arr, left, right) {
    if (left < right) {
        const partitionIndex = getPartitionIndex(arr, left, right);
            quickSort(arr, left, partitionIndex-1);
            quickSort(arr, partitionIndex+1, right);
    }
    return arr;

}

var getPartitionIndex = function (arr, left, right) {
    let pivot = arr[left], // Left most element is pivot
        partitionIndex = left + 1, // Since, left is the pivot
        i;

    for (i = left + 1; i <= right; i++) {
        if (arr[i] < pivot) {
            [arr[partitionIndex], arr[i]] = [arr[i], arr[partitionIndex]];
            partitionIndex++;
        }
    }
    [arr[partitionIndex], arr[left]] = [arr[left], arr[partitionIndex]];

    return partitionIndex;
}

// Test 1
console.log(quickSort([5,2,8,7,4], 0, 4));
```

**Question/Observation:**

1. Why does after first call to getPartitionIndex the `arr` becomes `[ 7, 2, 4, 5, 8 ]` instead of `[ 5, 2, 4, 7, 8 ]`, where partition index is 3 (4th item)?
2. If I make following change to get desired output mentioned in #1, even then program fails as it hit max call stack size.

```js
+ if (arr[partitionIndex] < arr[left]) {
        [arr[partitionIndex], arr[left]] = [arr[left], arr[partitionIndex]];
+ }
```

Comment: I suggest that you learn how to debug your own code. This is a crucial skill for every programmer. Check out https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ for some tips on how to debug.

Comment: I did debug for hours but got stuck at a specific issue. Modified the question for the "specific problem" as the blog you posted also suggests. thanks for commenting. ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

partitionIndex was going one past the last element < pivot. Fixes noted in comments. You might want to look at the wiki pseudo code for this. It uses hi / right for pivot, but the idea is the same.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort#Lomuto_partition_scheme

Hoare partition scheme is usually faster. Note that with a standard Hoare partition scheme, the pivot element ends up at the right end of the left-sub array or the left end of the right sub-array. Additional code could be added to isolate the pivot element, similar to Lomuto scheme:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort#Hoare_partition_scheme

```js
var quickSort = function (arr, left, right) {
    if (left < right) {
        partitionIndex = getPartitionIndex(arr, left, right);
        quickSort(arr, left, partitionIndex-1);
        quickSort(arr, partitionIndex+1, right);
    }
    return arr;
}

var getPartitionIndex = function (arr, left, right) {
    let pivot = arr[left],
        partitionIndex = left,    // fix
        i;

    for (i = left + 1; i <= right; i++) {
        if (arr[i] < pivot) {
            partitionIndex++;     //fix
            [arr[partitionIndex], arr[i]] = [arr[i], arr[partitionIndex]];
        }
    }
    [arr[partitionIndex], arr[left]] = [arr[left], arr[partitionIndex]];

    return partitionIndex;
}

// Test 1
console.log(quickSort([5,2,8,7,4], 0, 4));
```

Comment: Interesting. Thanks for taking out time to help with the debug and letting me know about Hoare and Lomuto's scheme. :)